# telepot error helper router: 'module' object has no attribute 'router'

Tags: python, telegram-bot

I'm try to use telepot to build my first telegram bot with python.
I want to route conversation by command, so I’ve read the documentation in [Telepot Helper Router](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/blob/master/REFERENCE.md#telepothelperrouter), but I don't know how can I use it.

So far, I have:

```
import telepot
from telepot.routing import by_chat_command

def on_site(chat_id,msg):
   #function code
def on_tick(chat:id,msg):
   #function code
def on_start(chat_id,msg):
   #function code
r = telepot.helper.router(by_chat_command(), {'site': on_site , 'tick':on_tick , 'start':on_start })
bot.routing_table['text']=r.route
bot = telepot.Bot('TOKEN')
bot.message_loop()
print ('Listening....')

#LOOP
while 1:
    time.sleep(10)
```

which gives me this error:

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'router'

on the line:

```
r = telepot.helper.router(by_chat_command(), {'site': on_site , 'tick':on_tick , 'start':on_start })
```

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Issue is that you are trying to call function, instead of Class.
If you check source of Telepot [here](https://github.com/nickoala/telepot/blob/master/telepot/helper.py#L785) you will see that `Router` is a class

So instead of:

```
r = telepot.helper.router
```

Use

```
r = telepot.helper.Router
```